# remove an xmlnode from an xmlnodelist based on a condition

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xmlnodelist , where I extract all elements starting with name `Store` :

```
XmlNodeList nodes = list[0].SelectNodes(@"node()[starts-with(name(), 'Store')]");
```

Which Gives me the output list

```
Name : Store1  , InnerXML = 100
Name : Store2  , InnerXML = 200
Name : Store3  , InnerXML = 300
Name : Store34  , InnerXML = 40
Name : Store42  , InnerXML = 40
```

Now , I would like to remove all stores that are not `Store1, Store2 & Store3` from the list of nodes . Is there a way I can do it  ?

```
for (int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
if (nodes[i].Name != "Store1" || nodes[i].Name != "Store2" || nodes[i].Name != "Store3")
nodes.RemoveChild(nodes[i]);
}
```

Please let me know..

Comment: Side note: please avoid [thank you notes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and instead try to format code without horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in your XPath expression and *not* select the nodes (instead of removing them later):

```
node()[starts-with(name(), 'Store') and name()!='Store1' and name()!='Store2' and name()!='Store3']
```

And use it in your code:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = 
    list[0].SelectNodes(@"node()[starts-with(name(), 'Store') and name()!='Store1' and name()!='Store2' and name()!='Store3']");
```

Or even

```
node()[starts-with(name(), 'Store') and number(substring-after(name(), 'Store')) > 3]
```

if you start counting from `1` and there is always a number after `Store`.

With this your nodelist will not contain any `Store1`, `Store2` or `Store3` nodes, and you won't need to remove anything.

Comment: I tried using the xpath expression you mentioned above : XmlNodeList nodes = 
    list[0].SelectNodes(@"node()[starts-with(name(), 'Store') and .!='Store1' and .!='Store2' and .!='Store3']"); . I dont see any fltering for store1, store2 & store3 happenning for this expression. Thank you !

Comment: But the last expression, using `substring-after` should work without any changes.